# Angular6 - Variable won't update

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I'm sorry I'm sure this is one of the most frequently asked questions about angular, and I found a ton but nothing's helping me here. I got a simple Observable - subscribe relationship with a variable.

my Service:

```
  activeRoom: number = 0; // we're starting in room 0

/* get the roomnumber from open-rooms to chat-window */
getActiveRoom(): Observable<number> {
return of(this.activeRoom);
}
```

my component:

```
constructor(
private activeRoomService: ActiveRoomService){}


ngOnInit() {

 /* Observe if we're changing rooms */
 this.activeRoomService.getActiveRoom().subscribe(newActiveRoom => {
   this.activeRoomChat = []; // clear the message board
   this.activeRoom = newActiveRoom;
 });
}

 click(){
  console.log("the following line doesn't work");
  console.log(this.activeRoom);
  console.log("the following line does work")
  console.log(this.activeRoomService.activeRoom);
}
```

I obviously can't update my component with a click every time, so option b is no option :D
What's the blatantly obvious thing I'm missing here?

Here's a working example.

Service:

```
private userArray: User[] = [];
  getUserArray(): Observable<User[]>{
  return of(this.userArray);
 }
```

component:

```
constructor(private backend: BackendService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.backend.getUserArray().subscribe(user => {
        this.userlist = user;
    //    console.log(user);
    });
```

Can someone please point a really really big red arrow to the thing I'm missing here?

Comment: i can't uderstand which is your problem

Comment: The variable this.activeRoom does not update in the component, when updated in the service. I can say for sure that the service updates the component since i can directly access it via  this.activeRoomService.activeRoom. So the broken link is between the subscription and the getter.

Comment: what contains newActiveRoom if you print it? it seems that you have omitted some code, where is updated activeRoom?

Comment: not entirely sure if I get your question right. newActiveRoom is the return statement of the getActiveRoom() function. The function itself returns an Observable<number> but with the statement, newActiveRoom is the number itself which is then transferred to this.activeRoom.
Exept: it isn't.

the setter for the activeRoom isn't the problem as it is working with the direct link, but I can tell you the two-liner:    
     setActiveRoom(roomID): void {
     this.activeRoom = roomID;
       }

Comment: so newActiveRoom is always 0?

Comment: yes. I literally just injected the component into another one and set the value remote. It did change in the console, but the html view (both with ngModel and the {{}} notation) wasn't affected, so this is no option either =/.

Comment: to  make sure: we're not only talking about the view - the html element of the component when talking about the subscription. When I subscribe to the observable, it won't change at all

Comment: I think you problem does not reside in the posted code. please provide a full working code to reproduce it, I can't see anything wrong

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time. the code is pretty interlinked, i try to extract the valid points. Thanks for the help to verify that the snippit itself is seemingly correct.  Could you link any platform on where to upload the code? the comment section here doesn't really seem accurate for it and I'm too unexperienced in the world of computer science to know any decent plattform =/

Comment: look at this, it's very simply to use: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: thank you very much. If you're interested I will try to extract all the relevant data about that. While we were talking I could fix the issue... Well i still don't get it, but it seems like you can't use observables for numbers... or.. i can't...here...

whatever, i changed the old:
  activeRoom: number = 0; 

  getActiveRoom(): Observable<number> {
    return of(this.activeRoom);
  }

   setActiveRoom(roomID): void {
    this.activeRoom = roomID;
  }

Comment: into:   activeRoom: Subject<number> = new Subject;

  public getActiveRoom(): Observable<number> {
    return this.activeRoom.asObservable();
  }

  public setActiveRoom(roomID): void {
    this.activeRoom.next(roomID);
  }

Comment: so now it works?

Comment: with the new code, yes :)

still no idea what actually was the problem with just doing the observable thingy, and I kinda wish i had my 4 hours back, but yes, at least a little progress today <3

thanks for sticking with me. TIL: don't use Observable<number> with the of() structure

Answer (score 1):

Changed

```
 activeRoom: number = 0; 
 getActiveRoom(): Observable<number> { 
 return of(this.activeRoom); 
 } 

 setActiveRoom(roomID): void {
  this.activeRoom = roomID; 
 }
```

to:

```
activeRoom: Subject<number> = new Subject; 
public getActiveRoom(): Observable<number> { 
 return this.activeRoom.asObservable(); 
} 

public setActiveRoom(roomID): void { 
 this.activeRoom.next(roomID); 
}
```

and it works. To be honest, I have no idea why or what changed, but I'm happy it works :D